# Emacs link widget gives the error "gui-get-primary-selection: No selection is available"

Tags: widget

I am reading the [The Emacs Widget Library](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/widget.htm).
The library describes the widget properties in general and not per widget.  So I'd like some more insights about the `link` widget properties and use.

- `:notify` property is  a "function called each called each time the widget or a nested widget is changed".
  Does a widget click implies a call of this function?
- `:action` property is a "function to handle user initiated events".  "Pressing RET invokes the function specified by :action".
  Does this entail a widget click?

Do I have to set `:follow-link 'mouse-face` or is it the default value for the property?

If I run the following snippet immediately after starting Emacs:

```
(require 'widget)
(with-current-buffer (get-buffer-create "test")
  (kill-all-local-variables)
  (let ((inhibit-read-only t))
    (widget-create 'link
           :notify (lambda (&rest ignore) (message  "You clicked"))
           "my link")
    (widget-setup))
    (switch-to-buffer (current-buffer)))
```

I get the error:

```
gui-get-primary-selection: No selection is available
```

I am using GNU Emacs 25.0.94.2 (x86_64-w64-mingw32) with Windows 10 x64.